# Relative URL Changes to Absolute When Setting the href Attribute of an Anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, dom

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = '/path';

// will give the absolute url: http://.../path
console.log(a.href);
```

Is it possible that a.href will return the original relative path '/path' without modifying the return value afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it -

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = '/path';

var domain = window.location.origin;
console.log(a.href.substring(domain.length));
```

Comment: Tx. But I'd like to see a solution without modifying the return value afterwards.

Comment: The href attribute will always be absolute. If you want, you can store the relative path in another attribute on the a tag.